# Ubuntu Django WebSocket connection to ... failed

Tags: django, websocket, django-channels

i am new to this field, i tried to run websocket in ubuntu but it gives error
[image] [image] i followed the instructions on this page([enter link description here](https://l.facebook.com/l.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fdivanov11%2Fdjango-channels-basic-chat.git%3Ffbclid%3DIwAR1gab4QndztuvjiL726aJRU05GHpEeieuPUiGrVJ672t0RXXnnpB0zVdmQ&h=AT2BnKAD5v73f38nhbtnKSEyIiPtRSTYVraNr1mNoWI1Lfy4V_sKRGp1oRGkh6preNZXoWukb8KHMXfuGFFZvN7PLzEv7JfwWreqtbjJjIP2-o3Q2KI7YAe5piGC4g)) i don't understand where the error is located.